# Handle PerformanceWarning while creating new columns with map

Tags: python, pandas

Full error:

> "PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider using pd.concat instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
> payouts[x] = ranking[x].map(prizes.set_index('Rank')['Payout'].to_dict())"

```
lineups = range(1, 5)
prizes = {'Rank':[1, 2, 3], 'Payout':[100, 50, 25]}
prizes = pd.DataFrame(prizes)
payouts = pd.DataFrame(lineups, columns=['Lineup'])

ranking = {'Lineup':[1, 2, 3, 4], 1:[1, 2 , 3, 4], 2:[2, 1, 4, 3], 3:[4, 1, 2, 3], 4:[1, 3, 4, 2]}
ranking = pd.DataFrame(ranking)

for x in range(1, 4):
     payouts[x] = ranking[x].map(prizes.set_index('Rank')['Payout'].to_dict())

payouts = payouts.fillna(-20)
```

Comment: Code that can be used to recreate `prizes`, `payouts`, and `ranking` would be helpful. We don't have access to `'payout.xlsx'` nor `lineups`.

Comment: Edited the original code to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Thank you. Much better, however, `ranking` and `num_sims` are still undefined.

Comment: As an aside, it appears you have 500 rankings, your `payouts` dataframe is going to end up mostly `NaN` if only giving payouts to the top 3 results. How do you want your results?

Comment: Ok, added ranking in a more simplified version than what I have and also how to deal with NaN's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping, we can create a `mapper` then [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to each column in `ranking` then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `payouts`:

```
mapper = prizes.set_index('Rank')['Payout'].to_dict()
payouts = pd.concat(
    [payouts,
     ranking[range(1, 5)].apply(lambda s: s.map(mapper)).fillna(-20)],
    axis=1
)
```

Alternatively we can [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) where values are beyond the max prize Rank:

```
mapper = prizes.set_index('Rank')['Payout'].to_dict()
payouts = pd.concat(
    [payouts,
     ranking[range(1, 5)].replace(mapper)
         .mask(ranking.gt(prizes['Rank'].max()), -20)],
    axis=1
)
```

Both produce `payouts`:

```
   Lineup    1    2    3    4
0       1  100   50  -20  100
1       2   50  100  100   25
2       3   25  -20   50  -20
3       4  -20   25   25   50
```

---

*Note in this example ranking contains the necessary information to build the DataFrame without initializing `payouts`:

```
mapper = prizes.set_index('Rank')['Payout'].to_dict()
payouts = ranking.copy()  # Create copy of ranking
cols = list(range(1, 5))
payouts[cols] = payouts[cols].apply(lambda s: s.map(mapper)).fillna(-20)
```

or

```
mapper = prizes.set_index('Rank')['Payout'].to_dict()
payouts = ranking.copy()  # Create copy of ranking
cols = list(range(1, 5))
payouts[cols] = (
    payouts[cols].replace(mapper).mask(ranking.gt(prizes['Rank'].max()), -20)
)
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

prizes = pd.DataFrame({'Rank': [1, 2, 3], 'Payout': [100, 50, 25]})
payouts = pd.DataFrame({'Lineup': range(1, 5)})
ranking = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lineup': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    1: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    2: [2, 1, 4, 3],
    3: [4, 1, 2, 3],
    4: [1, 3, 4, 2]
})
```